# Hibernate - Order results according to most matched Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I'm using Criteria API in Hibernate to search for candidates based on various parameters like skills, domains, designations, etc. I'm using the following code to get the search results:

```
Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(Candidate.class, "p");

    Criteria skillCriteria = criteria.createCriteria("skills", "s");
    skillCriteria.add(Restrictions.in("s.id", skillIds));
    //and many more criteria added in the similar way.
```

I want to get the results based on relevance. For eg, if a candidate matches maximum number of parameters, he should be placed first and so on. What will be the best way to achieve that in Hibernate?

Comment: I would suggest you to transform your result as your preference using a custom ResultTransformer. I dont think (according to my knowledge) it can be directly done through criteria.

Comment: I can't imagine sth like this even in pure SQL. Do you have any thing in mind?

Comment: Is Hibernate Search of any use in my case?